# Angular & Laravel Advanced Searching

Tags: angular, laravel, typescript, backend, angular-fullstack

I'm doing full stuck development using Angular12 as Front End and Laravel as BackEnd. I want to do a search using multiple values but I don't have any idea. I could search using a single value but I want to do with multiple values (AND operation).

**LARAVEL**

`api.php`:

```
Route::get('/project/search/{request}', [ProjectController::class, 'search']);
```

`ProjectController.php`:

```
public function search($request)
{
    if ($request==='business_divition') {
        return Project::where('business_divition', 'like', '%Business%')->get();
    }

    if ($request==='rank') {
        return Project::where('rank', 'like', '%rank%')->get();
    }
    
    //Single value search
    //return Project::where('rank', 'like', '%' .$request. '%')->get();
}
```

**Angular**

`data.service.ts`:

```
searchProjectData(data: any) {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/project/search',data);
}
```

`itemlist.component.ts`:

```
search() {
    this.dataService.searchProjectData(this.projects).subscribe(res => {
      this.projects = res; //right now 'res' value display as *null*
    })
}
```

`itemlist.component.html`:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="rankArr" name="rank" [(ngModel)]="project.rank" optionLabel="rank" optionValue="rank"></p-dropdown>
<p-dropdown [options]="divitionArr" name="business_divition" [(ngModel)]="project.business_divition" optionLabel="divition" optionValue="divition"></p-dropdown>

<button (click)="search()" type="button"></button>
```

I think itemlist.component.ts file search() method is wrong!

Comment: you need post() instead of get() method in your service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url doesn't look like the one in server side. This function will work. I used a dynamic url to fit all your cases.

```
searchProjectData (data: string) { 
let url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/project/search/" + data;
return this.httpClient.get(url);
 }
```